# Java changes Cyrillic to unicode like \uXXXX

Tags: java, http, apache-commons-httpclient

I am making an application in Java, that will log into my school diary using web api, so I will be able to make my own UI. As the title says, Java at some moment changes the cyrillic to unicode like \uXXXX symbolds. Here is the code on the Russian Stackoverflow: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452959/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81. Try to translate it, to understand more. When I am sending my request to https://httpbin.org/post instead of my LOGIN_URL with cyrillic symbols it returns them transformed, if I send request with ascii symbols, I get them back, and, in the linked post I mentioned the python project, which does exactly the same thing I want. And when I modify it to make it send request to httpbin, the cyrillic symbols are returned back! What do I do to fix my java code? 
 
 P.S. Currently I am switched to okhttp3 from apache http client (same problem), but, I can go back.

Comment: Is this solved since you provided an answer to your other question (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1457875)? Note that Unicode escapes in JSON have the same meaning as the corresponding Unicode code point, so any compliant JSON library should handle that fine. If you are using `String.format` in your `getRequestString` method, you should specify a `Locale` to make it independent of the default locale; and you might have to perform URL escaping on more parameters. Though with OkHttp you could use [`HttpUrl.Builder`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-http-url/-builder/)

Comment: Oh, I forgot about question here. Thank you. Well, problem was not with the encoding but because of two http headers was missing. Now my program works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my problem. It consisted not in the character encoding, but in the absence of two http headers, namely

```java
httpPost.setHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
httpPost.setHeader("Referer", Constants.BASE_URL);

(added to login request)
```